# Private test cases are not passing. What is the mistake here?

Tags: c++

Given N three-digit numbers, your task is to find bit score of all N numbers and then print the number of pairs possible based on these calculated bit score.

1. Rule for calculating bit score from three digit number:

From the 3-digit number,

· extract largest digit and multiply by 11 then

· extract smallest digit multiply by 7 then

· add both the result for getting bit pairs.

Note: - Bit score should be of 2-digits, if above results in a 3-digit bit score, simply ignore most significant digit.

Consider following examples:

Say, number is 286

Largest digit is 8 and smallest digit is 2

So, 8*11+2*7 =102 so ignore most significant bit , So bit score = 02.

Say, Number is 123

Largest digit is 3 and smallest digit is 1

So, 3*11+7*1=40, so bit score is 40.

2. Rules for making pairs from above calculated bit scores

Condition for making pairs are

· Both bit scores should be in either odd position or even position to be eligible to form a pair.

· Pairs can be only made if most significant digit are same and at most two pair can be made for a given significant digit.

Constraints
N<=500

Input Format
First line contains an integer N, denoting the count of numbers.

Second line contains N 3-digit integers delimited by space

Output
One integer value denoting the number of bit pairs.

Test Case

Explanation
Example 1

Input

8 234 567 321 345 123 110 767 111

Output

3

Explanation

After getting the most and least significant digits of the numbers and applying the formula given in Rule 1 we get the bit scores of the numbers as:

58 12 40 76 40 11 19 18

No. of pair possible are 3:

40 appears twice at odd-indices 3 and 5 respectively. Hence, this is one pair.

12, 11, 18 are at even-indices. Hence, two pairs are possible from these three-bit scores.

Hence total pairs possible is 3

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

vector<int> correctBitScores(vector<int>);
vector<int> bitScore(vector<int>);
int findPairs(vector<int>);

int main() {
    int a, b;
    int pairs = 0;
    vector<int> vec;
    vector<int> bitscore;
    cout << "\nEnter count of nos: ";
    cin >> a;
    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
        cin >> b;
        vec.push_back(b);
    }
    bitscore = bitScore(vec);

    pairs = findPairs(bitscore);
    cout << "Max pairs = " << pairs;

    return 0;

}

vector<int> correctBitScores(vector<int> bis) {
    int temp = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < bis.size(); i++) {
        temp = bis[i];
        int count = 0;
        while (temp > 0) {
            temp = temp / 10;
            count++;
        }
        if (count > 2)
            bis[i] = abs(100 - bis[i]);
    }
    /*cout << "\nCorrected" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < size(bis); i++) {
        cout << bis[i] << endl;
    }*/
    return bis;
}

int findPairs(vector<int> vec) {
    int count = 0;
    vector<int> odd;
    vector<int> even;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++)
        (i % 2 == 0 ? even.push_back(vec[i]) : odd.push_back(vec[i]));

    for (size_t j = 0; j < odd.size(); j++)
        for (size_t k = j + 1; k < odd.size(); k++) {
            if (odd[j] / 10 == odd[k] / 10) {
                count++;
                odd.erase(odd.begin()+j);
            }
        }

    for (size_t j = 0; j < even.size(); j++)
        for (size_t k = j + 1; k < even.size(); k++) {
            if (even[j] / 10 == even[k] / 10) {
                count++;
                even.erase(even.begin() + j);
            }
        }
    return count;
}



vector<int> bitScore(vector<int> v) {
    int temp = 0, rem = 0;
    vector<int> bs;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) {
        int max = 0, min = 9;
        temp = v[i];
        while (temp > 0) {
            rem = temp % 10;
            if (min > rem)
                min = rem;
            if (max < rem)
                max = rem;
            temp = temp / 10;
        }
        int bscore = (max * 11) + (min * 7);
        bs.push_back(bscore);
    }
    /*cout << "\nBit Scores = " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < size(bs); i++) {
        cout << bs[i] << endl;
    }*/
    bs = correctBitScores(bs);
    return bs;
}
```

Comment: The mistake here is post for help to debug without input, expected output and actual output posted.

Comment: I'm afraid this is way too much work for a volunteer Q&A. You're going to have to debug it yourself!

Comment: First, you doing incorrect `erase()`, second you allowed to have only 2 pairs with same significant digit, but you don't have this condition. As aside, you don't need function `correctBitScores()` (which is incorrect to boot), all you need is `bscore%100`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried doing it very simple c++ code as per my understanding of Que,can you just verify it more test cases.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
 using namespace std;

int main() {
int n,count=0;

cin>>n;
vector<int>v(n);

for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    cin>>v[i];
    string s = to_string(v[i]);
    sort(s.begin(),s.end());
    int temp = (s[s.length()-1]-'0')*11 + (s[0] - '0')*7;
    v[i] = temp%100;
}

unordered_map<int ,vector<int>>o,e;
for(int i=0;i<n;i=i+2){
    o[v[i]/10].push_back(i+1);
}
for(int i=1;i<n;i=i+2){
    e[v[i]/10].push_back(i+1);
}
count=0;
for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
    int os=o[i].size(),es=e[i].size();
    if(os==2)
        count++;
    if(es == 2)
        count++;
    if(os>2 || es>2)
        count += 2; 

}

cout<<count;
}
```